# Trouble Catching System.NullReferenceException in C# Application Using SQL CE

Tags: c#, sql-server, try-catch, nullreferenceexception

I have an application that keeps crashing and only says "Application has stopped working". In the details it said it was due to a System.NullReferenceException. I cannot replicate this exception in my development environment(which is x86, testing on x64 on a server where I can scale the threads up) for unknown reasons and I cannot seem to find a way to catch the error. I have try-catch blocks around everything. I am thinking it is due to some SQL CE queries returning null values, even though they are within the try-catch blocks and have if statements testing for null values.

I really don't think testing on an x64 machine is causing any issues. I'm going to try to replicate the issue on my development environment but it could take a very long time as my application uses a lot of threads and connected to the internet a lot and I have a slow connection.

EDIT: I managed to repro in my dev environment. The error was occurring when trying to write to a text box by using the dispatcher. I was wring ex.Message (where ex is my Exception) but it appeared that ex was null and caused the error. How can ex be null in a try-catch? This seems to make no sense to me.

Comment: Your posting does not contain a single question mark so I'm guessing it contains no question, right?!?

Comment: Sorry, asking how I can deal with the error.

Comment: Try to open the event viewer and see what is going on.

Comment: since you love try..catch. try putting a catch..try inside every catch clause.. and another catch inside it.. theis way you will have multi-dimensional try..catch.. just kidding.

Comment: The exception wasn't null. Maybe you caught a null exception.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you **shouldn't** put try-catch around everything. That is exactly what keeps you from finding the error. The combination of `NullReferenceException` and lots of try-catch is really a warning that you should stop swallowing all errors. Exceptions are **exceptions** - don't just routinely catch them all. If your software is prone to lots of exceptions, there are errors in your code that need to be fixed properly.

1. Create a branch of your code in your source control system *(you are using one, right?)*.
2. Remove all(!) try-catch blocks.
3. Run the code and debug it.

Then you'll have some proper error messages to ask questions about.